# IN clause is slow when sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have simple SQL with `IN` clause and ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE fieldA IN ('value1', 'value2') 
ORDER BY fieldB
```

I've also created the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_fieldA ON my_table (fieldA)

CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_fieldA_fieldB ON my_table (fieldA, fieldB)
```

There are millions of rows in this table.

I have very slow queries when I run it with multiple values in `IN` clause:

```
Sort  (cost=800.35..802.21 rows=744 width=601) (actual time=36.409..36.423 rows=5 loops=1)
   Sort Key: "fieldB"
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB
   Buffers: shared hit=18 read=13
   I/O Timings: read=29.326
   ->  Index Scan using idx_my_table_fieldA on my_table  (cost=0.57..764.86 rows=744 width=601) (actual time=5.597..35.819 rows=5 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (fieldA = ANY ('{value1,value2}'::text[]))
         Buffers: shared hit=15 read=13
         I/O Timings: read=29.326
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=238 read=54
   I/O Timings: read=81.777
 Planning Time: 94.622 ms
 Execution Time: 36.528 ms
(14 rows)
```

The *idx_my_table_fieldA* index is used.

But it's very fast if I run it for single value in `IN` clause:

fast SQL example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE fieldA IN ('value1') 
ORDER BY fieldB
```

This is the query plan:

```
Index Scan using idx_my_table_fieldA_fieldB on my_table  (cost=0.57..153.17 rows=149 width=601) (actual time=1.435..1.440 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (fieldA = 'value1'::text)
   Buffers: shared hit=3 read=2
   I/O Timings: read=1.313
 Planning Time: 0.194 ms
 Execution Time: 1.472 ms
(6 rows)
```

The multicolumn index is used in this case.

Could you recommend me how to improve this query? I use an ORM system (Hibernate + Spring Data), so it's better not to use native SQL. It would be great to solve this problem using another appropriate indexes (if it's possible).

Comment: 36ms doesn't seem "very slow" to me. How fast do you need that to be.

Comment: The second query is faster, because it doesn't need to sort anything (as only a single row is returned). The first query must be slower as it has to retrieve more rows and then sort them at the end. Also in the second case most 2 of 3 buffers where already in the cache, in the first case 13 buffers had to be retrieve from disk (which took 29ms of the 36ms). If you run the first query again, it's highly likely to be a lot faster as no more I/O is involved.

Comment: Planning Time: 94.622 ms vs  Planning Time: 0.194 ms, that's the real difference. I have no ideal why planning such a simple query takes so long.

Comment: We have postgres on the host with 20CPU, 32GB and SSD storage. Sometimes there is high frequence of such queries (100-200 QPS). At this moment CPU is ok (<80%), memory is OK (<20 GB is used), but we have abnormal IOWAIT (up to 60%). This SQL query takes 80-1500 ms. Looks like the index is not cached? Why it is? We have a lot of free memory.

Comment: The caching of catalog information happens per connection (=backend process). Do you use a connection pool, or are you constantly opening and closing the connections physically? If you run the `explain (analyze)` for the slow query twice do you see any change in the planning time?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: it's the retrieval of the catalog information that makes planning time so high. I guess it's the first time a query was run against that table in that connection

Comment: The planning time on that first query looks like it was the first query run on a new connection (or for that matter, the first query run after the whole system was rebooted.)  I very much doubt that that is representative of all queries with more than one thing in the IN list.

Comment: Yes, the planing time is so long because it was the first query execution on a new connection.
I've repeated the query and planning time now is 0.232 ms.
Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score -2):

This query is slow because the "planer" (called optimizer in other RDBMS) is very limited.

In such cases (with a list of values in a IN operator), the query is transformed in Oracle or SQL Server in several queries with a unique value, then results are concatenates, this way to have benefits from indexes.
But it seems that Postgresql does not rewrite your query this way.

You can manually test if a rewrite will do a better plan...

Comment: If the planner is the culprit, how do you explain the I/O timing on the index? I/O Timings: read=29.326 This is where most of the time is spend, waiting for disk.

Comment: Probably because this query has been the first to access to those pages and the data was not in cache...

Comment: Could be, but what has that to do with the planner/optimizer? What query plan would you expect to perform better?

Comment: A UNION ALL between two queries seeking the index, one for each values... What Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server do.

Comment: But it is using the index:          Index Cond: (fieldA = ANY ('{value1,value2}'::text[]))

Comment: @Frank_Heikens but with a SCAN not a SEEK...

Comment: The index above is a b-tree, so it performs a B-tree traversal. There is no need the read the entire index. To my (limited) knowledge, SQL Server is doing the same thing when performing an index seek.